# How to setValue of a specific index within an array? (Apps Script)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm working on a personal google sheet for a D&D character sheet, and learning a little Apps Script in the process.

The current struggle is copying values from one column to another if it matches criteria (currently just "if not blank")

I have the columns in a range (also tried two separate ranges) but can't figure out how to setValue (or setValues) to a specific index.

Here's what I've got and am trying.

```
function longRest() {

  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main");

  var resources = mainSheet.getRange('F36:G44');

  for (var i = 0; i < resources.getValues().length; i++) {
    if (resources.getValues()[i][1] != "") { 
      resources[i][0].setValue(resources.getValues()[i][1]);
    }
  }
```

To clarify the above, the intent is that it will check G36 on Main, and as long as it isn't blank, copy it's value into F36. Rinse and repeat through G44.

Currently it's giving me "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')". (Same issue with setValues and no other changes)

I'm sure the solution here is fairly simple, I'm just tired at this point and not making sense of the docs and not finding a question that matches mine enough to figure it out. So I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just on first glance., resources[i][0] do not give u a cell to set value, that's not how range works. Do this, instead of getting the value of the range in multiple places, first get the whole data with dataRange().getValues(). Then compare the respective array indexes in forloop and replace values of respective items based on your conditions. Then outside of the for loop set the value of the whole sheet. Do you understand what I'm saying?

Comment: @gorkhali1234 I'm not totally sure. I created a new variable for ```resources.getValues()```  So I wouldn't be performing the function over and over. I don't seem to have trouble accessing the values by index, for example Logger.log(resourceValues[0][1]) doesn't have an issue. The part I can't figure out is how to replace the specific indexes.
Also I'm not sure what you mean by "then outside the for loop set the value of the whole sheet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If second column has value set first column to value in second column

```
function longRest() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var vs = sh.getRange("F36:G44").getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => r[0] = r[1] ? r[1] : r[0]);
  sh.getRange("F36:G44").setValues(vs)
}
```

Before:

|  | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 36 | F36 |  |
| 37 | F37 | G37 |
| 38 | F38 |  |
| 39 | F39 | G39 |
| 40 | F40 |  |
| 41 | F41 | G41 |
| 42 | F42 |  |
| 43 | F43 | G43 |
| 44 | F44 |  |
| 45 | F45 | G45 |

After:

|  | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 36 | F36 |  |
| 37 | G37 | G37 |
| 38 | F38 |  |
| 39 | G39 | G39 |
| 40 | F40 |  |
| 41 | G41 | G41 |
| 42 | F42 |  |
| 43 | G43 | G43 |
| 44 | F44 |  |
| 45 | F45 | G45 |

- [Condtional Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! If you could, would you mind explaining what is happening within the forEach function? I'm not sure how ```r => r[0] = r[1] ? r[1] : r[0]``` is working, and I think I'll need to to do something like this on my own in the future. I've figured out that it's a ternary operator with the ?:, but I am not sure what the logical expression part is, especially the ```=>```

Comment: It's an assignmennt with a  [Condtional Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code and provided required functionality details, to implement following required functionality: "it will check cell "G36" in google sheet "Main", if it is not blank, its value will be copied into cell range from cell "F36" to cell "G44", using google apps script, this code can be checked.

```
function longRest() {
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main");
  var inputValue = mainSheet.getRange('G36').getValues();
  if(inputValue[0][0] != '')
  {
    var outputRange = mainSheet.getRange('F36:G44');
    outputRange.setValue(inputValue);
  }
}
```